# How to detect and redirect traffic only from in-app iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, .htaccess, redirect, user-agent

I see a lot of information out there about how to detect traffic by checking the user-agent of incoming traffic... but I want to detect and redirect ONLY traffic sent from within my iPhone app. To be clear, I DON'T want to redirect users who open safari on their iPhone and browse to my site.

Is this possible? How?

If you're curious, the situation is that I created a basic iPhone app which loads a `UIWebView`. In early versions the UIWebView loaded an external site: example.com. I've since released an update that points to iphone.example.com and I want to make better use of the original url (example.com). The release has already been accepted by the iTunes store, but I don't know of any way to make sure that all pre-existing users have updated. And I don't want break the functionality for non-updated users. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to redirect any in-app traffic (from non-updated app users) to the new endpoint: (iphone.example.com), but STILL allow normal mobile traffic to view the portfolio site at example.com.

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: Google Analytics seems to be able to distinguish Mobile Safari traffic from in-app iOS traffic. So that tells it MUST be possible somehow.

Comment: Well, you can try and examine the user-agent but it seems fraught with risk http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/10/18/the-perils-of-ios-user-agent-sniffing/